# Configure npm to search for unscoped package in private registry first before searching in public registry

Tags: npm, npx

I am looking for a way to configure npm so that it can find both scoped and unscoped packages in my private registry and still can find other public packages in public registry.

I have a private npm registry containing scoped (@company/package1) and unscoped packages (package2).
If I configure .npmrc file as below, then npm cannot find package2.

```
@company:registry=https://private.registry
```

If I configured .npmrc file as below then npm cannot find a public package.

```
registry=https://private.registry
```

Is there a way to use the scoped registry config but still let npm look for package2 in my private registry first before checking the public registry?